What's the new star in the reopen vote?
Now a reopen votes shows as
Share Edit Follow Reopen (2*) Flag
What's with the new star?
I think I must have noticed this since a week to 10 days

It means you cast one of the reopen votes.  It's a very recent feature.
Tnx Lowri for the link
